# How to add wordpress plugin to the free blog?

Tags: wordpress

i had created a free word press blog, but i did not add plugin.
Is there no plugin option for free members? my blog and my admin page screen shot is uploaded in http://ponnusamyror.wordpress.com/how-can-i-add-plugin-in-free-wordpress-account/? please anyone show me the result

Comment: You can't add plugins http://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use plugins in wp.com blogs. First check Appearance>Widgets for useful sidebar items. There’s a lot that can be done with Text widgets, which accept html (but no javascript or flash). 
http://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/

***Most WordPress.com users won’t find a Plugins tab in your dashboard. We include and configure the plugins for you, so you don’t need to worry about them.***

Hope this may help you!!!